# How to Change Hover Information on Pressing some Keys

Tags: eclipse-plugin, hover, editor, jface

I am working on extending hover information in Java Editor. I need to change the Hover with my information only when certain keys are pressed. Anyone please guide me

Thanks

Comment: Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: I finally found the answer for this                                                                   1. First register hover in the editor first with the default contentType and the statemask of the key being pressed. (setTextHover)                                                        2. Implement the ITextHover for displaying your information

Comment: You can post this as answer.